# Как в es6 класс в метод добавить event.keyCode?

Tags: javascript

Как в es6 класс добавить в метод `event.keyCode` на чистом ***javascript***?

```js
class SomeClass {
  onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      console.log('pressed: ENTER');
    }
  }
```

Comment: чтобы у параметра функции было поле keyCode  достаточно при вызове функции передать объект с этим поле. То есть в текущем коде ничего менять не надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
  }

  onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      console.log('pressed: ENTER');
    }
  }
}

const itemSomeClass = new SomeClass();
```

Comment: [keyCode помечен как deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) , не используйте его!